# Hover radius flutter data picker

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I’m wondering if there is a possibility to change the hover radius of buttons inside a Date Picker component? The default radius looks too big. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Our current code only changes colors, but **not the radius of the hover**.

```
return Theme(
data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
    primary: accentColor, // header background color
    onSecondary: colorSecondary,
    onPrimary: colorBlack, // header text color
    onSurface: colorBlack, // body text color
  ),
  textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      primary: colorBlack, // button text color
    ),
  ),
),
child: Center(
  child:
    ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxWidth: Responsive.isMobile(context) ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width : 500.0,
        maxHeight: Responsive.isMobile(context) ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height : 490,
      ),
      child: child,
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

try using Theme Widget for date picker

```
showDatePicker(
                  builder: (context,child){
                    return Theme(
                      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                          primary: Colors.black, // header background color
                          onPrimary: Colors.white, // header text color
                          onSurface: Colors.black, // body text color
                        ),
                        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.black, // button text color
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: child!,
                    );
                  },
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate: DateTime(2022),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2025),
                )
```

Comment: this does not change the hover radius :( I edited my question

Comment: try using SfDateRangePicker class instead of showDatePicker